# Adapt old geo to D3 v5, how to express a queue of Promise?

Tags: d3.js, geo

I am adapting an [old version D3 map visualization](https://bl.ocks.org/ruliana/1ccaaab05ea113b0dff3b22be3b4d637) to modern D3v5: first step, to D3v4, is running [with this source](https://gist.github.com/ppKrauss/0c33364240e841fa23e78b21005f792c/5d2b12081e8fbe7a7beded5e3ce5760ca1388bb5), but to the  final step I need to convert  Promises, from old queue,

```
d3.queue().defer(d3.json,"file.json").(ready);
```

to the modern v5 style... **How to express in v5 style?**
 Seems that is  something as

```
var brMap = d3.json("file.json");
Promise.all([brMap]).then(ready)
```

but is not working.

---

PS: where the v5 **simple** examples?

Comment: This should work, have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534634/5768908). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi @GerardoFurtado, thanks. Perhaps that clues solve my problem... I have syntax/structure problems only. I will test as soon as possible, and back to say

Comment: @PeterKrauss Since you have only one task—namely `d3.json—`to wait for, your code can be simplified even more to `d3.json("file.json").then(ready)`; there is no need to use `Promise.all()` in this simple case.

Comment: @PeterKrauss Apart from the above mentioned simplifications I suspect you are still using the callback function's old signature from the example: `function ready(error, shp)`, am I right? Note, that the signature of [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) slightly differs from the Node.js callback style `function(error, data)` used by previous versions of D3...

Comment: @PeterKrauss ...Now, that there is no `error` parameter anymore this would store the loaded data in the first parameter (now misleadingly mis-named `error`) leaving the second parameter `shp` as `undefined` all the time. You might want to have a look at an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53704123/4235784) of mine explaining how to deal with this in a more detailed way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GerardoFurtado and @altocumulus, the answer was on his comments, here merging all.

---

There are some globals (perhaps not a best practice)

```
var g;
```

In "after page load" context run

```
svg = d3.select("etc..")
g = svg.append("g")
// ...
d3.json("file.json").then(ready);
```

where the function `ready()` is something as

```
function ready(shp) {
  var data1 = topojson.feature(shp, shp.item1);
  //... draw map appenging features to global g
}
```

See the final result of the solution [here](https://bl.ocks.org/ppKrauss/raw/0c33364240e841fa23e78b21005f792c/).